# Saving copy of old table entry to another table when updating table entry with SaveChanges()?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

Im working on an online store project where I have already made it possible for an administrator to update different table entries via the store gui (like items, user profiles, orders etc). SaveChanges(); is used to save the changes.

Im currently trying to figure out how to make this work:

1. An entry in table "items" gets updated.
2. Before the entry in the table "items" gets updated, a copy of the old entry gets saved into a table named "history-items".
3. The copy that is saved to "history-items" preferably has a timestamp.

How would I go about doing this? (As you might tell, I just recently picked up visual studio, and am pretty new to everything)

Thank you.

Comment: I would use triggers in the database for that.

Comment: It might work out easier to save the current item in the history table. You can intercept all the items in the `SaveChanges()` method of the `DbContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are atleast 3 ways to do this:

1. If you are using SQL Server 2008 or newer this is now built in functionality, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx
2. If you opt not to use that then the simplest solution is to use database triggers.
3. If you want to do it in C# code, then you need to read the original values before saving, and save these original values to the history table. For reading original values see: [How to get original values of an entity in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133974/how-to-get-original-values-of-an-entity-in-entity-framework)

I would go for option 1 if possible.