# How to check that which properties/entries are modified and which are not on Editing a record in EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am developing an MVC 5 application using EF 6. The auto-generated POST method for Edit is:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Address,Phone,SSNo,D1")] ABC abc)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         db.Entry(abc).State = EntityState.Modified;
         db.SaveChanges();
     }
     return View(abc);
}
```

Is there any procedure/method by which I can get that which entries are modified and what were the original values of those entries. I have tried the method marked as an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265257/getting-all-changes-made-to-an-object-in-the-entity-framework) question but it didn't get any changes although changes have been made, i.e. the loop does not iterates.

My code is:

```
 public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Address,Phone,SSNo,D1")] ABC abc)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          db.ABCs.Attach(abc);
          var myObjectState = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(abc);
          var modifiedProperties = myObjectState.GetModifiedProperties(); 
          foreach (var propName in modifiedProperties)
          {
                Console.WriteLine("Property {0} changed from {1} to {2}",
                propName,
                myObjectState.OriginalValues[propName],
                myObjectState.CurrentValues[propName]);
          }
          Console.ReadKey();
          db.Entry(abc).State = EntityState.Modified;
          db.SaveChanges();
          return Json(abc);
     }
     return View(abc);
 }
```

ABC model contains many values other than mentioned in method parameters, but I am only passing those which can be edited

What I am trying to do is to maintain a log in my database of all the changes made to a document. I want to include only the changes and the original values before modification in the log not the complete record.

How can I get this?

Comment: _"But I am unable to use them."_ - why?

Comment: I am not getting how to use them.. They have different types

Comment: See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265257/getting-all-changes-made-to-an-object-in-the-entity-framework), it's explained pretty well there. Update your question with actual code if you can't get it to work.

Comment: @CodeCaster.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented this extension method for you:

```
namespace YourProject.Extensions
{
    public static class ModelExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> ModifiedValues<T>(this T obj, T modifiedObject) 
        {
            foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => !p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual))
            {
                if (property.GetValue(obj).ToString() != property.GetValue(modifiedObject).ToString())
                {
                    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(property.Name, property.GetValue(modifiedObject));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's neither the fastest nor the most efficient, but worked in my tests.

Use:

```
var originalEntity = await db.Entities.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.EntityId == modifiedEntity.EntityId);
var modifiedValues = originalEntity.ModifiedValues<MyEntity>(modifiedEntity).ToList();
```

Comment: THANKS a lot.. It helped me very much.. again thank u very very much for writing the extension for me. I am relieved,